# Perl: Delete element in hash based on their values

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash and want to delete some elements (element = key+value). It is easy to delete an element by key but I don't know how to do if the condition to delete is based on the value.

```
my %h = (  'a' => 1
         , 'b' => 1
         , 'c' => 2
       );

# delete by key
delete $h{'c'};

print map { "$_ $h{$_}\n" } keys %h;
# a 1
# b 1
```

I would like to delete using the value:

```
delete %h value >1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can efficiently loop over the entries with `each` and `delete` matching ones:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 2
    );

while (my ($k, $v) = each %h) {
    delete $h{$k} if $v > 1;
}

print Dumper(\%h);
```

From [the `each` documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each) (Emphasis added):

> Any insertion into the hash may change the order, as will any deletion, **with the exception that the most recent key returned by each or keys may be deleted without changing the order.**

This means that the above loop can safely look at every element of the hash and delete all of those that meet the criteria.

---

You can also use a [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices) to delete multiple entries at once. Just have to build a list of the keys to remove, for example by filtering the result of `keys`:

```perl
delete @h{grep { $h{$_} > 1 } keys %h};
```